# update position of geolocation marker in Openlayers 3

Tags: geolocation, openlayers-3

I wan't to have a marker on the map, which position is dynamically updated.
When I create the layer inside the function of the geolocation.on('change'-event it works, but the layer is added each time the geolocation changes. Therefore I wanted to create the layer outside that function and update only the position of the marker.

With the folowing code I get an 'TypeError: a is null'

```
var geolocation = new ol.Geolocation({
  projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
  tracking: true,
  trackingOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    maximumAge: 2000  
  }
});     

var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
    opacity: 0.75,
    src: './_img/marker_.png'
  })
});

var pos1 = geolocation.getPosition();

var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
   geometry: new ol.geom.Point(pos1)
});         
var iconSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [iconFeature]
});
var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: iconSource,
  style : iconStyle
});

map.addLayer(iconLayer);

geolocation.on('change', function() {
  var pos_upd = geolocation.getPosition();
  iconFeature.getGeometry().setCoordinates(pos_upd);
  view.setCenter(pos_upd);
  view.setZoom(18);        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code a bit, so that I created first an iconFeature, that wasn't already bound to a ol.geom.Point()-position. By this way there was no need to use geolocation.getPosition().
Later in the geolocation.on('change')-event I assigned the actual position to the geometry of the iconFeature.

Works like espected

```
// add an empty iconFeature to the source of the layer
  var iconFeature = new ol.Feature();   
  var iconSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [iconFeature]
  });    
  var iconLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: iconSource,
    style : iconStyle
  });    
  map.addLayer(iconLayer); 

// Update the position of the marker dynamically and zoom to position
  geolocation.on('change', function() {
    var pos = geolocation.getPosition();
    iconFeature.setGeometry(new ol.geom.Point(pos));
    view.setCenter(pos);
    view.setZoom(18); 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser Geolocation API, which is wrapped by `ol.Geolocation`, is asynchronous. After initiation, `geolocation.getPosition()` will always return `undefined` until the first change event.

The proper thing to do is to add the feature once you get a coordinate, in the change event handler.

You will need to use a conditional to determine if you should add ore update a feature.